# How to declare a constructor that has default parameter?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

How do I write a constructor that can take in a default parameter? Do I declare the default parameter when declaring private data members or inside the constructor itself?

```
    Color class:
    private:
        int red;
        int blue;
        int green;
    public: 
        Color(int r, int b, int g) {red = r; blue = b; green = g;}

    Table class: 
    private: 
        double weight;
        double height;
        double width;
        double length;
        Color green;
    public: 
        Table(double input_weight, double input_height, double input_width, 
double input_length, Color green = green(0, 0, 60)){
        weight = input_weight; 
        height = input_height; 
        width = input_width; 
        length = input_length;
    }
```

I would like to be able to write a constructor that takes a default parameter. But I don't know how to write one (The above Table constructor is the one I'm having problems with). I would like to have an object Table that has different weights, heights, widths, lengths, but all tables will be green.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: `green(0, 0, 60)` makes no sense. Perhaps you meant `Color(0, 0, 60)`? (Voting to close as a simple typographical error)

Comment: Could you explain why it would be Color? I am trying to initialize the object green to 0, 0, 60. Isn't Color just a data type?

Comment: Because `Color(0, 0, 60)` creates a Color object, passing 0, 0, and 60 to its constructor. (It could also call a function or function pointer, if `Color` was one, or if `Color` was an object with an `operator()`, it would call that, but none of those are actually true here).

Comment: `green` is not a type, function, function pointer, or object with an `operator()`, so you can't call it.

Comment: @jasonadams `Color(0, 0, 60)` is a `Color` object with no name. `Color blue(0, 0, 60)` declares that `blue` is a`Color` object with a name `blue`.  `blue` and `Color(0,0,60)` are both `Color` objects; one has a name and one doesn't.  `green(0, 0, 60);` is none of the above and is an error.   When you are providing a default value, you have to supply an expression which represents a `Color` object.  `Color(0, 0, 60)` does that, as would `blue` if you had previously declared `blue` somewhere (you cannot provide a declaration as part of a default value specification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use member initializing list:

```
public: 
    Table(double input_weight, double input_height, double input_width, double input_length)
    : weight(input_weight) 
    , height(input_height) 
    , width(input_width) 
    , length(input_length)
    , green(Color(0, 0, 60))
{

}
```

As others had pointed out, you have a typo in your original code, where you should use Color(0, 0, 60) to call the constructor.

If you really want to keep your Table constructor signature, you can do this:

```
public: 
    Table(double input_weight, double input_height, double input_width, double input_length, Color default_color=Color(0, 0, 60))
    : weight(input_weight) 
    , height(input_height) 
    , width(input_width) 
    , length(input_length)
    , green(default_color)
{

}
```

Basically defining a default parameter for constructor follow the same rules as default parameter for any function. But you should only have the Color parameter in the constructor if you really need it there.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer, I guess I'm still not understanding the syntax. When we declare an object like Color blue, we'd do something like Color blue(0,60,0); why is it not the case here?

Comment: This signature does not allow `green` to be defaulted , as OP requested (i.e. invoke the constructor with only 4 arguments)

Comment: when you do blue(0, 60, 0), you define a object blue, but the constructor invoked is Color(int, int, int). you can do it like green(0, 0, 60), it will call the same constructor Color(int, int, int), you can also use Color(0, 0, 60), which will call the copy constructor.

Comment: Good advice to use the ctor-initialize list though

Comment: @jasonadams: i modified the signature so Color green is not in Table constructor anymore, so green always defaults to green.

Comment: @swang now the constructor is not callable with 5 arguments. He wants it to be callable with either 4 or 5 ; if called with 4 then `Color(0,0,60)` will be used in lieu of the 5th

Comment: @MattMcNabb: why does it have to be callable with 5 arguments? he wants green to be default to always green.

Comment: @swang, I'm a big time newbie when it comes to classes, so here's a stupid question, if we modify the signature to only take 4 arguments, does that mean the data member Color green needs to be eliminated?

Comment: @swang he asked "How do I write a constructor that can take in a default parameter? " . "Default parameter" means a parameter whose argument may either be given or omitted.  He is not asking "How do I provide a default value to a class member variable".

Comment: @jasonadams: no, it just means it's constructed to a default value you provided. You can for example, still read the value, or provide a function to modify it. Whether you need the 5th argument in the constructor, I don't know, it depends on how you plan to use Table.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: ok, he also asks " I would like to have an object Table that has different weights, heights, widths, lengths, but all tables will be green.", that's why i think he doesn't need a constructor with default parameter. But i added it in the answer anyway.